# Robotics - Euler Angles from Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, robotics

In a robotics application (3d Cartesian Space), I need to transform my Point position and orientation in a particular frame to the world frame. The Frame Position and Orientation is known and I was able to get the position by calculating the Rotation Matrix and concatenating it inside the Homogeneous Transformation Matrix alongside the Frame Position.

However, how can I get the point's orientation (RX,RY,RZ)?

To exemplify:
I have a Frame positioned at:
X = 234.067
Y = -662.889
Z = -168.332
RX = -0.115
RY = 0.095
RZ = -63.417

And a Point "P" in reference to that Frame at:
X = 36.851
Y = 3.669
Z = -14.5
RX = 0
RY = 0
RZ = 71.913

After calculating the Rotation Matrix and Homogeneous Transformation Matrix for Point "P" in reference to World Frame I reached the position:
X =  253.80191194
Y = -694.1939878
Z = -182.90041625

**Which is right.**

**However, how can I calculate the Orientation (RX,RY and RZ)?**
RZ seems to be just adding RZ of "P" to RZ of my Frame. So, -63.417 + 71.913 = 8.496 degrees

But for RX and RY I have no idea. The answer is: RX = 0.054 and RY = 0.139, (all in degrees) but I don't know how it got there.
[Positions were denoted in mm]
[Angles in degrees]
[Rotation Matrix Calculated using RZRYRX, in this order]
[Rotation is Extrinsic - Fixed Frame ]

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: So through my researches I found that I need to multiply my Rotation Matrix from the Frame with the Rotation Matrix of the Point (which has only RZ rotation). Then with this new rotation Matrix I must extract the Euler angles from it.

Being:
RX = atan2(r32/cos(RP), r33/cos(RP))
RY = atan2(-r31, sqrt(r32^2 + r33^2))
RZ = atan2(r21/cos(RP), r11/cos(RP))

Please, feel free if any wishes to clarify a little more with more theory.